# Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernateContext.xml]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat8

I have upgraded to Tomcat 8 and got this exception while deploying my application in Linux.

However in windows 7 the application is deployed successfully.

Does the hibernate dependencies act different under different OS?

In my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <versionPackageName>com.translations.globallink.connect.core</versionPackageName>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</maven.build.timestamp.format>         
    <spring.security.groupId>org.springframework.security</spring.security.groupId>
    <spring.security.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>3.3.0.GA</hibernate.version>
    <releaseControl.version>2.0.43</releaseControl.version>
</properties>
```

and dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </exclusion>                
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Inside the target/war I saw these libraries after building:

> hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar
>
> hibernate-annotations-3.3.0.GA.jar
>
> hibernate-c3p0-3.3.0.GA.jar
>
> hibernate-core-3.3.0.GA.jar
>
> hibernate-validator-5.1.0.Final.jar
>
> hibernate-ehcache-4.1.12.Final.jar
>
> hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.GA.jar

Aren't these dependencies compatible in Linux?

Adding stack trace :

```
ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernateContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:589)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2476)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:857)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newConfiguration(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:818)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:549)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace? Besides the error posted, can't you also provide the root cause of the error?

Comment: Never, repeat Never, mix versions of a framework, regardless of which framework. You are mixing hibernate 3.2, 3.3 and 4.1 jars and expect it to work. That will never happen. Also hibernate validator isn't even compatible with hibernate 3 so that won't work either. Cleanup your dependencies and use compatible versions.

Comment: Would you suggest me compatible versions to use. I have added property like <hibernate.version>3.3.0.GA</hibernate.version> and using  <version>${hibernate.version}</version>

I have no idea about cause of the mismatch seen .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections`

You have a dependency conflict.

Comment: Excluding conflicts did the job. Thanks. Used eclipse dependency hierarchy to resolve the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

can you show your web.xml also?
I think It is the problem with your configuration file i.e. hibernate.cfg.xml is not at the correct/required.
I think the problem with your code is that it uses jars of different versions of hibernate. The use of jars of same version of hib ernate is highly recomended and ur problem may be solved.

Comment: In windows 7 OS my application is deployed without any exception. In centOS(Linux), application is deployed on tomcat 7. The above exception I get only when I try to deploy on tomcat 8 in Linux.

my web.xml file and hibernate.cfg.xml file are inside <application>/WEB-INF

Comment: If you hv not entered your configuration path in web.xml. then just try this for a minute: keep your hibernate.cfg.xml file parallel to the packages i.e. in /src folder and try to use jdk-1.8.0 with tomcat 8.

Comment: and one more thing use the jars of same version of hibernate.